# Unreal Engine bUseControllerRotation problem

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, game-development

Hi for the past hour I have been struggling to make my 3d camera system work.All necessary elements are inside my character class but for some reason character still rotates with the camera

```
bUseControllerRotationPitch = false;
bUseControllerRotationRoll = false;
bUseControllerRotationYaw = false;

GetCharacterMovement()->bOrientRotationToMovement;
GetCharacterMovement()->RotationRate = FRotator(0.0f, 540.0f, 0);
```

Comment: Nevermind i give up and just did it inside BP but this still bothers me so much

Answer (score 0):

**This might help!**

The default you set in the editor should be the default at runtime. Make sure that you aren't resetting it somewhere else in your code, like maybe in BeginPlay. And make sure that the pawn you are spawning is the one where you changed the defaults in.

[Another Similar post](https://www.reddit.com/r/unrealengine/comments/iexn1n/use_controller_rotation_yaw_wont_start_as_true/)